# QSFP to 4 x SFP+ breakout not working in HP Procurve 3500yl J8693A

Tags: switch, transceiver

I have bought a Netronome Agilio CX smartNIC which has QSFP interface. My switch HP 3500yl J8593A has 4xSFP+ interfaces. I bought Amphenol QSFP to 4xSFP+ breakout DAC. But the switch complained about "Not HP transceiver". How to get around this issue? I tried to configure the switch to allow 3rd party transceiver but unfortunately, this specific switch doesn't have this feature. Any suggestions on how to get things working would be of great help to me.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

HPE switches only accept HPE-branded transceivers (of the right series) by default.

If there's a quite recent firmware version for the 3500yl (16.02 or newer), you could use `(config) allow-unsupported-tranceiver` to make the switch accept non-HPE transceivers/DACs. Then replug the DAC to make it accepted.

If not (it seems the last firmware is 15.04.003), you'll need to buy a HPE-compatible breakout cable (the 3500yl accepts J928xB and J930xA series DACs) - various vendors offer 100% compatible, usually much cheaper variants. Make sure you don't have the same problem with the NIC, but most NICs accept generic MSA DACs.

Alternatively, forget about DACs and use 10GBASE-SR transceivers (J9150A for the 3500) with multi-mode fiber.

Comment: The problem is that the 3500yl switch doesn't support the allow-unsupported-transceiver even with the latest firmware. And I am not able to find any compatible DACs. I even reached out to some suppliers but they said that HPE has made it hard for them to create compatible DACs.

Comment: As far as [I can see](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01814544), the 3500yl is compatible with the X242 and X244 DAC series. You can rather easily find compatible, 3rd-party cables. For the NIC, there are QSFP+/SFP+ adapters. Alternatively, you could use 10GBASE-SR modules (J9150A) which really are all around.